# using JSON in Rails, Backbone and Mustache - formats seem to differ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js, mustache

I am trying to put together a Rails app, with backbone.js and mustache templating. I am finding that the JSON required by backbone isn't compatible with the JSON required by Mustache. (I started out following this tutorial [Cloudedit -a backbone.js tutorial by example](http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/), but I want to use Mustache where he is using JST.

For backbone we must set ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false. For my model (person with firstname and surname) the data sent by rails from /people looks like this:

```
[{"firstname":"Jane","surname":"Jones"},{"firstname":"Janet","surname":"Jensen"}]
```

My mustache template looks like this:

```
<h3><a href='#new'>Create New</a></h3>
<h4>People</h4>
<ul>
{{#people}}
<li>{{firstname}} {{surname}}</li>
{{/people}}
</ul>
```

and from the mustache docs I expect that what it wants to see is

```
{"people":[{"firstname":"Jane","surname":"Jones"},{"firstname":"Janet","surname":"Jensen"}]}
```

*Edited out me transforming the JS collection back to JSON and sending to Mustache. 
Don't need to do that. Mustache.js expects to see js objects, not strings of JSON.*

By the time I get to Mustache.to_html I have a backbone collection of models. The models have the attributes *firstname* and *surname*. It looks like this in firebug:

```
collection
  +_byCid
  +_byId
   length 2
  - models  [object { attributes=(...), more...}, object {attributes=(...), more...}]
    - 0 object { attributes=(...), more...}
      ....... some more properties of the object
        + attributes object {firstname="Janet", surname="Jensen"}
```

There seem to be a couple of problems here. 
1. There is no mention of the name of the collection (people). I can get around that in various ways I guess, at least by using {{#models}}..{{/models}} in the template.

1. The attributes are buried deeper than Mustache.js looks. When it gets down to trying to find the 'firstname' tag in the object, it looks for object['firstname'] and doesn't find it, but object.attributes['firstname'] has the correct value.

It seems I'm all mixed up here....So what am I doing wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide the code used to initialize the template?

Comment: Ah, and I guess you have [a possible answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516297/can-mustache-iterate-a-top-level-array)

Comment: Well, I went home and started afresh, rather than trying to experiment with an existing application. Found a minor problem, but in the end it came down to the same thing: Mustache is looking for data at object.firstname, but the data is in object.firstname.attributes.

Comment: @yves - not sure what you mean by the code used to initialize the template? In my clean attempt to do this I have put the template directly into the variable passed to Mustache. Thus: tpl="<h3>..."; out=Mustache.to_html(tpl,collection)

Answer (score 2):

I now have a solution of a sort (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234071/access-nested-backbone-model-attributes-from-mustache-template)).

```
jsonForTemplate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.people)); //this works for a single item
context['people']=jsonForTemplate;    //need to add this for a collection
out = Mustache.to_html(tpl,context);
```

but it feels as though this sort of jumping-through-hoops shouldn't be necessary. I will check to see if handlebars offers anything better.

Comment: This solved it for me also.  Have you discovered a better way?  Is mustache the wrong tool for use with backbone?

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution would be to use `toJSON` on the Collection as documented here - http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-toJSON

```
out = Mustache.to_html(tpl, collection.toJSON);
```